# How to hide the parent of an unchecked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of random/dynamic generated div checkboxes:

```
<div>A1 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A1'> </div>
<div>A2 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A2'> </div>
<div>A3 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A3'> </div>
<div>B1 <input type='checkbox' name='B[]' value='B1'> </div>
<div>B2 <input type='checkbox' name='B[]' value='B2'> </div>
<div>C1 <input type='checkbox' name='C[]' value='C1'> </div>
```

What I am trying to do is when the user:

1. checks any A then the others will hide (entire div) but all A will still show.
2. unchecks a checkbox, then all A, B, C will show again.

This is because I am preventing the user from checking a mix of options.

PS:
You can provide a solution that might need me to modify the generated output of checkboxes.

Comment: using :NOT, .not(), adding class for div for different, attr("name"), .parents().find(name).not(name).hide() ....... and more but all are not working, then only i post here for solution

Comment: Rather than hide the other checkboxes, why not just diable them? That way the user knows other options are still there, just not availble with their current selection.

Comment: user matter, if you not hide, then they will say you mess up the screen! that's it. not user-friendly

Comment: Careful! Unless desired behavior, most answers including the OP has a bug in their implementation. If you check 2 A[] boxes and then uncheck 1, the other boxes will appear.

Comment: yes, most of the solution do have a little bug there, so we must not copy and paste code from others, check on my solution in the bottom, i did add in the checking of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, especially dbaseman (get me ideal) :
ok, Here is my code after referring from you all.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    var sta = $(this).is(":checked"); sta=(sta==true?1:0);
    if(sta==1){
        var thisName = $(this).prop("name"); thisName=thisName.replace("[]","");
        $("div input[type=checkbox]:not([name^=" + thisName + "])").parent().hide();
    }else{
        var num = $("[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if(num==0){
            $("div input[type=checkbox]").parent().show();
    }
    }
});
```

so far code able is performing as what i need.
Ps: i am still weak on jquery travelling part

Ps: Edited on re-opening all checkboxes part
Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some JQuery traversing to hide the non-matching elements:

```
// add the event handler
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    // get whether checked or unchecked
    var checked = $(this).prop("checked") === true;

    // get the name of the clicked element (eg, "A[]")
    var thisName = $(this).prop("name");

    // get the name of the clicked element (eg, "A[]")
    var thisName = $(this).prop("name");

    // get the grandparent element
    $(this).parent().parent()
        // get all the checkboxes
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        // filter to only the ones that don't match the current name
        .filter(function(i, e) { return e.name != thisName; })
         // hide or display them
        .css("display", checked ? "none" : "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/RS4T7/1/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(':checkbox').parent().hide();
$('input:checkbox[name|="'+thisName+'"]').parent().show();
} else {
    $(':checkbox').parent().show();
}    
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code bellow:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    var identifier = $(this).val().substring(0, 1);

    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(identifier) != -1) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });

    if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").parent().show();
    }

});
```

You can try on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MULJQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
  if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
     $('input:checkbox').parent('div').hide();
     $('input:checkbox[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').parent('div').show();
  }else{
      if(!$('input:checkbox[checked="checked"]').length){
         $('input:checkbox').parent('div').show();
      }
  }
})
```

​

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/uRd3e/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can simple do it like this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
       var Name = $(this).prop("name");    
        $('div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("name") != Name;
}).hide(); 
    }
    else
    {
      $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
      $('input[type=checkbox]').parent('div').show();
    }

});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YK3s/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This will hide all other checkbox types when FIRST of a type is checked and show all the other checkbox types when ALL of the checked box type are unchecked:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    // get the name attribute
    var nameAttr = $(this).prop("name");
    // check how many checkbox inputs of that name attribute are checked
    var checkedLength = $("input:checkbox[name=\"" + nameAttr + "\"]:checked").length;
    // if 0, display other checkbox inputs, else if 1 hide all of the rest
    if(checkedLength == 0) {
        $("input:checkbox[name!=\"" + nameAttr + "\"]").parent().show();    
    }else if(checkedLength == 1) {
        $("input:checkbox[name!=\"" + nameAttr + "\"]").parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Careful! Unless desired behavior, most answers including the OP has a bug in their implementation. If you check 2 A[] boxes and then uncheck 1, the other boxes will appear.

Comment: Did you mean to comment on your own post or someone else's?

Comment: @RobG, I don't have an "add comment" option on any other post. This was my only outlet for the warning :)

Answer (score 0):

Overwhelmed by choice! Here's a plain JS version that just disables members of the non–selected groups.

I think that's better than hiding them so users can see the other options after they've selected one. Otherwise, to see the other options again, they must deselect all checkboxes in the group.

Note that `div` is a parent of the inputs, the listener passes a reference to the element and the related event object, modify as required.

```
<script>
function doStuff(div, evt) {
  var checked, el, group, j, inputs, name, re;
  var t = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  if (t.nodeName && t.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && t.type == 'checkbox') {
    inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
    name = t.name;

    // Set checked to true if any input with this name is checked
    group = document.getElementsByName(name);
    j = group.length;
    while (j-- && !checked) {
        checked = group[j].checked;
    }

    // Loop over inputs, hide or show depending on tests
    for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      el = inputs[i];

      // If name doesn't match, disable
      el.disabled = checked? (el.name != name) : false;
    }
  } 
}
</script>

<div onclick="doStuff(this, event)">
<div>A1 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A1'></div>
<div>A2 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A2'></div>
<div>A3 <input type='checkbox' name='A[]' value='A3'></div>
<div>B1 <input type='checkbox' name='B[]' value='B1'></div>
<div>B2 <input type='checkbox' name='B[]' value='B2'></div>
<div>C1 <input type='checkbox' name='C[]' value='C1'></div>
</div>
```